# MenuItemTemplate calling a method instead of URL

Tags: 2007, development, custom-actions

How can I add my method instead of URL of a website, I can see another option as "ClientOnClickScript" but not sure how exactly I can do it tho, here's my code

```
public class MyUserControl: WebControl
{
    private MenuItemTemplate _action;

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
       _action = new MenuItemTemplate
       {
         Text = "hahahahaha",
         Description = "whatever",
         ImageUrl = "/_layouts/images/abc.gif",
         ClientOnClickNavigateUrl = "http://www.freehostingmarket.co.uk"
       };

       Controls.Add(_action);
    }

    private void myMethod(string linkToURL, string documentLibraryName)
    {
       //mYcode
    }
}
```

I got these 4 options I think but not sure which one will work,

- ClientOnClickNavigateUrl
- ClientOnClickPostBackConfirmation
- ClientOnClickScript
- ClientOnClickUsingPostBackEvent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle click event of `MenuItemTemplate`.
1. Subclass `MenuItemTemplate`, `IPostBackEventHandler` and declare an event inside the class to which you can subscribe.
2. Instantiate this class instead of `MenuItemTemplate` and handle the event. That's it.

Browse this excellent article [Handling a PostBack](http://translate.google.co.in/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://www.cnblogs.com/ceci/archive/2009/08/01/1536547.html&prev=/search?q=menuitemtemplate%2bclientonclickusingpostbackevent%2bexample&start=20&hl=en&sa=N&noj=1&biw=1366&bih=643&sa=X&ei=I-lPUdDiGs_trQfi5oC4Dg&ved=0CFoQ7gEwBzgU) for more details. Good Luck!.